# Как писать первое слово в усеченном названии?

Tags: прописная

Есть Запорожский национальный университет. А если в тексте газетной статьи его называют просто национальный университет, нужна ли здесь прописная буква?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Следует писать: Национальный университет (первое слово с большой буквы).

Полное название нашего вуза - Сыктывкарский лесной институт. Иногда слово "Сыктывкарский" опускают. В этом случае слово "Лесной" пишется с прописной или строчной
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Верно написание с большой буквы.

Российская академия наук - если слово "академия" встречается в тексте, как оно пишется - с прописной или строчной? 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
Возможно написание как с прописной, так и со строчной буквы.

Как следует написать *институт физкультуры*, если это не полное название учреждение, а используемое в быту, например: Его сын учится в (И)институте (Ф)физкультуры. 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
Корректно: Его сын учится в Институте физкультуры.

Если полное наименование учреждения Институт химии ДВО РАН, то , когда в контексте употребляется слово институт, с какой буквы ( прописной или строчной) его писать?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
В официальных бумагах слово Институт нужно писать с большой буквы, если оно употреблено в качестве эквивалента полного названия. В остальных случаях слово институт пишется со строчной буквы.

В названии Института сравнительных испытаний первое слово пишется с большой буквы, но если дальше в тексте упоминается только слово Институт - то с какой буквы лучше писать? 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
В условном значении - с прописной.

У Мильчина:

3.14.2.    Неполное название, заменяющее полное

С прописной буквы пишется первое (или единственное) слово усеченного названия. Напр.: Государственный литературный музей — Литературный музей, Центральный дом художника — Дом художника, Большой зал Московской консерватории — Большой зал Консерватории, Московский театр сатиры — Театр сатиры, Государственный Кремлевский дворец — Кремлевский дворец, но: театр «Современник».

Надо ли это понимать так, что если в тексте речь идет именно о конкретном объекте, то всегда усеченное название начинается с прописной? Или же только в приведенных Мильчиным названиях?

Но София как-то на подобные вопросы отвечала так:

Написание прописной буквы в усеченных названиях возможно только в ЧАСТНЫХ случаях. Это касается следующих написаний:
Государственный Литературный музей (Литературный музей),
Государственный Исторический музей (Исторический музей),
Государственный академический Большой театр (Большой театр),
Государственная Третьяковская галерея (Третьяковская галерея).

Выходит, кроме этих случаев, надо писать первое слово в усеченных названиях со строчной? В частности, национальный университет, лесной институт, когда речь идет соответственно о Запорожском национальном университете и Сыктывкарском лесном институте?

Answer (score 6):

На практике встречается **три вида названий для учреждений**: (1) имя собственное (полное официальное название), (2) имя собственное (неполное официальное название), (3)нарицательное существительное (школа, институт, академия, музей).

**В официальных названиях** учреждений первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, например: Российская академия наук, но: Академия наук СССР. Такое официальное название полностью характеризует данное учреждение, дополнительных комментариев для его узнавания не требуется.

**В усеченных (неполных) названиях** с прописной буквы также пишется первое слово: Академия наук, Литературный музей,  Национальный университет, но при этом по тексту должно быть понятно, о каком учреждении идет речь.

**Нарицательные названия** учреждений (строчная буква) также могут использоваться, если говорящий не пользуется официальным названием учреждения, называя только его статус, при этом слушатели и читатели понимают, какое учебное заведение имеется в виду. Даже в одной и той же статье автор может перейти от официального названия (Государственный литературный музей) к нарицательному (литературный музей).

**Например, академия - это нарицательное существительное,** которое может писаться различным образом в разных ситуациях общения (выбор автора).

АКАДЕМИЯ 1. Название научных учреждений, задачей которых является развитие наук или искусств. А. наук России. А. художеств. Почётный член академии. Выборы в академию.  2. Название некоторых высших учебных заведений. Лесотехническая а. Военно-воздушная а. Выпускник академии. Поступить, принять в академию. Исключить из академии.

Примеры

Никогда до войны в институте, **в Академии наук** не пришлось ему слышать разговоры об этом. Он учился **в Академии художеств** и получил прекрасное образование. Той же осенью **в академии** распределяли дачи, и Павлу Алексеевичу предложили подать заявление.Представляю себе, что начнётся в институте да и **в Академии**.

Answer (score 1):

> Ответ справочной службы русского языка Следует писать: Национальный
>   университет (первое слово с большой буквы).

"Справка" опять глупость сказала. Национальных университетов в Украине до фига, а если судить по справкиной аргументации, они воспринимают это как имя собственное.

> Надо ли это понимать так, что если в тексте речь идет именно о
>   конкретном объекте, то всегда усеченное название начинается с
>   прописной? Или же только в приведенных Мильчиным названиях?

Понимать надо именно так, как у Мильчина: любое усеченное **название**. Сочетание "национальный университет" не является усеченным названием, а относится к категории нарицательных родовых слов, как школа, драматический театр, кремль (если не московский), литературный музей (который не "Государственный") и т.п. Вообще такое усечение не совсем правильно, правильнее бы было "усечь" до "университета" просто, ибо в Украине, насколько знаю, "ненациональных" сейчас в Украине и не осталось. Но коли уж оно фигурирует, то только со строчной.

> Российская академия наук - если слово "академия" встречается в тексте,
>   как оно пишется - с прописной или строчной? Ответ справочной службы
>   русского языка: Возможно написание как с прописной, так и со строчной
>   буквы.

Это верно, ***если речь идет о РАН***. Академия - она у нас одна, всякого рода отраслевые, малые и зарубежные не воспринимаются на бытовом уровне как просто "академии". Академия - это и родовое слово и название одновременно.   Но понятно, что ни один из множества провинциальных национальных университетов на такую "Академию" не тянет.