# С какой буквы писать название в косвенном падеже?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Скажите, пожалуйста, с какой буквы (строчной или прописной) пишется название университета, если оно находится в коссвеном падеже? Мне почему-то кажется, что прописная буква пишется только в именительном падеже, а в случае принадлежности объекта к субъекту ("университет" в штате "Массачусетс"), субъект пишется со строчной.

1 **Со времени основания клиники по снижению стресса в медицинской школе при массачусетском университете в 1979 году Кабат-Зинн и коллеги вылечили 16 000 пациентов.**

Так как не уверен, что это название университета, привожу его англоязычную версию.

> Since founding the Stress Reduction Clinic at the University of Massachusetts Medical School in 1979, Kabat-Zinn and colleagues have treated 16,000 patients

Во втором примере непонятно, с какой буквы писать слово "оренбургских".

2 **Сегодня на одном из нескольких оренбургских заводов проходил митинг за повышение заработной платы рабочим.**

Заранее, благодарю вас за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

> Скажите, пожалуйста, с какой буквы (строчной или прописной) пишется
>   название университета, если оно находится в коссвеном падеже?

Падеж существительного на выбор заглавная/прописная не влияет.

> Мне почему-то кажется, что прописная буква пишется только в
>   именительном падеже, а в случае принадлежности объекта к субъекту

не понял. где тут именительный падеж, субъект-объект, принадлежность?

> ("университет" в штате "Массачусетс"), субъект пишется со строчной.

Да, здесь строчная, только падеж здесь ни при чем.

"университет в штате М.", "университета в штате М.", "университету в штате М.", - во всех падежах.

Здесь все проще. Заглавное в родовом слове используется в том и только в том случае, если это первое слово в полном название ("Университет экономики"). Иначе - со строчной ("Российский университет дружбы народов", Московский авиационный университет и т.д.). Это распространяется на все падежи.

[Как писать первое слово в усеченном названии?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423809)
Во всех остальных случаях, написание - со строчной буквы.

> университет" в штате "Массачусетс"

Это что-то очень заумное. Есть два университета - ***Университет Массачусетса*** (он же ***Массачусетский университет***) и ***Университет штата Массачусетс*** - все три сочетания пишутся по общим правилам - как указано.

> Since founding the Stress Reduction Clinic at the University of
>   Massachusetts Medical School in 1979, Kabat-Zinn and colleagues have
>   treated 16,000 patients

Со времени основания Клиники снижения стресса при Медицинской школе [в составе] Мичиганского университета в 1979 г. Кабат-Зин и его коллеги вылечили 16000 пациентов.

> Сегодня на одном из нескольких оренбургских заводов проходил митинг за
>   повышение заработной платы рабочим.

Так. Строчная.
Оренбургский - прилагательное, в состав имени собственного не входит. Мотивов для заглавной нет.

Comment: Перед Кабат-Зин запятая не нужна.

Comment: _behemothus: Иначе - со строчной ("Российский Университет Дружбы Народов", Московский Авиационный Университет и т.д.)._ === И где здесь строчная?

Comment: slava1947 - Спасибо. ))) Скопировал на автопилоте.

Comment: @oleedd *Перед Кабат-Зин запятая не нужна* - да спасибо.

Comment: _behemothus: ...Дружбы Народов_  (?) === См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%8B+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2&all=x

Comment: @slava1947 - о господи... Спасибо. Исправили уже б давно, ))) сказал же что бес попутал.

Answer (score 0):

Если название переходит в прилагательное, то пишется с маленькой буквы:

`киевские заводы, московские предприятия`.

(второй пример правильный)

Но название самого заведения пишется с большой буквы:

`Массачусетский технологический институт`.

Есть такое заведение - `The University of Massachusetts`. Следовательно, имея его ввиду, в русском языке нужно тоже писать с большой буквы - `при Массачусетском университете`.

Примечание: от падежа это не зависит; в английском языке правила больших букв отличаются.

Comment: oleedd, большое спасибо Вам за ответ! Не подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти это правило? Я в сборнике Розенталя, например, не могу его найти. Также, хочу уяснить для себя, чтобы не делать подобных ошибок.

Comment: Если организация уникальная в мире, то все слова с большой буквы (ООН). Тут много правил - https://www.profiz.ru/sr/7_2008/pravila_napisania_oficial/.